# get_current_screen() return null

Tags: plugin-development, functions, filters, hooks

I want to put JavaScript code on certain pages in frontend. But the output return null .

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {

    $screen = get_current_screen();
    var_dump( $screen );

}, 999 );
```

Comment: get_current_screen() won’t do anything on the front end. It’s for getting the admin screen. What value do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_current_screen` is an Admin API, it can't be used on the frontend, only in `/wp-admin` screens.

If you want to run javascript code only on certain pages, either enqueue it on those pages, or load it on all pages and check the body classes, or many other methods. `get_current_screen` is not the way to do it.